# how to automatic detect song playing?

Tags: audio, audio-playback, speech-recognition

i’m planing on using a raspberry to automatically detect any song playing in a room and display it’s album art, is there a framework/api capable of song recognition? like soundhound or shazam?

Comment: google can recognize music

Comment: your question does not belong here, because it is not Raspberry Pi specific

Answer (score 0):

also interested. Did you find anything? My plan is to create a device that automatically shows album art on a screen when I DJ/

Comment: this site is not a forum ... please do not use an "answer" to ask your own question ... please delete this